# MVC how reload page keeping the data in textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

(MVC)How to RedirectToAction and keep the content of a Html.Textbox in MVC4?  This is my controller how do I fix it and what goes in the view?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string ssn)
{
    var exist = false;
    var record = _db.Citations.Where(u => u.SSN == ssn).FirstOrDefault();

    if (record != null)
    {
        exist = true;
        return RedirectToAction("EditDetails", new { id = record.CitationID });
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "SubmitAward", ssn);   // wiped out ssn! I need to keep the ssn
        // so that the user can fill out the form.
    }
```

Comment: on redirecttoaction page data will always lost..use return view() instead...

Answer (score 0):

If your get action is like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string ssn)
{
.........
..........
.........
}
```

then do like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "SubmitAward", new { ssn = ssn});
```

but if it is the same index view of post action which is posted in question, you can pass the object back to view if your view is strongly typed to this class:

```
return View(record);
```

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Index", "SubmitAward", new {ssn = ssn});

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Index", "SubmitAward", new {ssn = ssn}); does not work, it wipes out the ssn, not strongly typed Html.Textbox("ssn", null). return View(record) does not work because the form needs data else I get an error. Is there another way to keep the textbox contents?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "SubmitAward", new { ssn = ssn});
```

And your redirect action will be

```
public ActionResult Index(string ssn)
{
    ViewBag.SSN=ssn;
    return View(record);
}
```

And your view will contain textbox like

```
@Html.TextBox("SSN",ViewBag.SSN)
```

It may helps you..